# How to interpret Solidity documentation

Tags: solidity

I am reading through the documentation (https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.5.3/types.html) and came across the '**' notation. The sentence "*For example, with uint32, this is 0 up to 232 - 1.*"

What does 2**32 - 1 mean?

Is it 2 to the 32nd power?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes. 2**32 means 2 to the 32nd power.

'**' is the exponentiation symbol.